# Angular form error-TypeError: Class constructor Validators cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: html, typescript, angular7-router

I'm getting the following angular form error -

```
ERROR TypeError: Class constructor Validators cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at forms.js:1480
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:1476)
    at FormControl.validator (forms.js:1418)
    at FormControl._runValidator (forms.js:4089)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:4050)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:4656)
    at FormBuilder.control (forms.js:8951)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:9011)
    at forms.js:8990
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

My HTML:

```
<form class="formLogin" [formGroup]="personalForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="form-group  rtl">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label pull-right" for="mail"> your email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input type="text" formControlName="mail" [value]="person.Email" placeholder="myAddress@gmail.com" class="form-control ltr textBox" email [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.mail.errors }" />
  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.mail.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.mail.errors.required">requird</div>
      <div *ngIf="f.mail.errors.email">invalid address!</div>
  </div></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-group  rtl">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label pull-right" for="phone">your phone</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input type="text" formControlName="phone" [value]="person.Phone"  class="form-control ltr textBox" placeholder="000-0000000" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.phone.errors }" />
  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.phone.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.phone.errors.required">requird!</div>
      <div *ngIf="f.phone.errors.pattern">digits only!</div>
  </div></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-group rtl">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label pull-right" for="username">your username</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" (focus)="incorrectData=false" [value]="person.UserName" formControlName="username" class="form-control textBox " [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
     <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">  
       <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">required!</div>
     </div></div>
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <div class="form-group rtl">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label pull-right" for="password">your password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input type="password" (focus)="incorrectData=false" [value]="person.Password" minlength="6" formControlName="password" class="form-control textBox" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">requird!</div>
      <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">password length minimum 6 letters!</div>
</div></div>
</div>
 <br>
</form>
```

My ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user.service';
import { User,UserEnum } from 'src/app/classes/User';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-details',
  templateUrl: './personal-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-details.component.css']
})
export class PersonalDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
person:User;
personalForm:FormGroup;
submitted :boolean;
  constructor(private userSer:UserService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder){ }
ngOnInit() {
    this.person=this.userSer.userDetailes;
        this.personalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email:['',[Validators.required,Validators.email]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6),Validators]],
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            phone:['',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(10),Validators.minLength(9),Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')]]});}
  get f()
  { return this.personalForm.controls; }
  saveUser() {}
  onSubmit()
  {
    this.submitted = true;
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.personalForm.invalid) 
    {return;}
    this.saveUser();}
}
```

userService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService   {
userDetailes:User=null;
}
```

I have good form imports for my app.module and other forms in my project work well. I think the problem is in this component.

Comment: Hi there. I've edited your question to show the error message at the top. I suspect English is not your native language so I made a few word changes to make it easier to understand.

Having your error message and question before you code lets people know what they are looking to fix without needing to scroll past all your code first so it's better to have that at the start. I hope someone is able to help you with the solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

instead of:

> password: ['',
>   [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6),Validators]],

i had to write:

> password: ['',
>   [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6),Validators.maxLength(10)]],

Answer (score 1):

just as written above, your problem is because you are referencing the validators in a wrong manner. You need to include the method you are trying to  call or invoke. In this case, your line

```
password: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6),Validators]],
```

Should be

```
password: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6),Validators.maxLength(20)]],// or any other measure you wish to put in place.  Validators is the problem here
```